# slick affecting my javascript code after adding .not(".slick-initialized")

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to implement two slick sliders on my website, somehow when I use .not(".slick-initialized") for my first slider, it breaks down all my other javascript code of my website, so the rest of the code does not work correctly, also the second slider does not work, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? Are errors reported?

Comment: there are no errors shown in the console, but the other javascript code does not work on my website

Comment: you can see my js code here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434037/multiple-slick-caroussel-uncaught-typeerror-cant-access-property-add-s)